# How to save event in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript

how do i save this events even after refreshing the page in fullcalender.js
this events after refreshing sets back to its location 
and does not update  .
as events are switched to another date after refresh they sill font update

after which file should i write in to make this changes and what should i write to make this changes

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<link href='fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />

<script src='moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar.js'></script>
<script>

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      defaultDate: '2018-05-15',
    selectable: true,

      editable: true, 

      events: [
        
       
        {
          title: 'Meeting',
          start: '2018-05-15T10:30:00',
          end: '2018-05-15T12:30:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Lunch',
          start: '2018-05-15T12:00:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Meeting',
          start: '2018-05-15T14:30:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Tea Hour',
          start: '2018-05-15T17:30:00'
        },
        
      ]
      

    
    });

  });

</script>

<style>

  body {
    margin: 40px 10px;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  #calendar {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id='calendar'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To persist your changes you will need to use a database. Fullcalendar only provides only the functionality, not the persistence.

Another workaround without a Database would be the use of `localStorage`. There you can store the events client-sided and check if if events are stored in the `localStorage`. If there are stored events, apply them to the calendar. 
But you can not store an event and see it on another client without a database.